# Format MomentJS to Rails DateTime

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reactjs, momentjs, ruby-on-rails-5

How do you format `moment()` to Rails datetime?

Im using [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) and Rails 5 as the back end.

**React:**

```
let newDate = this.state.startDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm')
console.log(newDate); #=> 2016-10-11 08:46
```

Looking at the [momentjs formats](http://momentjs.com/), I see nothing close to rails datetime format ie: `Mon, 10 Oct 2016 15:16:29 UTC +00:00`

The aim is to pass `newDate` as `params` to a rails controller: `params[:new_date]`

**Update:**

[cema-sp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3218479/cema-sp)'s answer was the final part to my answer but I was getting errors. To solved this:

```
# JS:
let newDate = this.state.startDate.format(); # no format type

# Controller:
DateTime.strptime(params[:new_date], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*moment.js* object `newDate` may be formatted in any string you like (for example like in the question `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm` or default format) and sent to the server:

```
const newDate = this.state.startDate.format()
...
fetch(apiEndpointUrl, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    new_date: newDate,
  })
}).then(...)
...
```

The only thing is that you have to parse `params[:new_date]` on the Rails backend.
Use simple *DateTime* class `parse` method or more performant `strptime` (provide it choosen format).

If you want to update model you may use setter method:

```
def new_date=(value)
  parsed = if value.is_a? String
             DateTime.parse(value)
             # Or more performant
             # DateTime.strptime(value, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
           else
             value
           end

  write_attribute(:new_date, parsed)
end
```

If you need to work with the date in controller, just parse it with one of *DateTime* methods:

```
new_date = DateTime.parse(params[:new_date])
# Or
new_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:new_date], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z')
```

Comment: If you override `#new_date=`, you'll get errors when you try to assign an actual `DateTime` to it. May want to add `if value.is_a? String`.  Also, you need to pass the parsed value to `super` or call `write_attribute`, just assigning to `@new_date` won't persist it.

Comment: @gmcnaughton thank you for the comment! I fixed answer

Comment: Thanks for the fix! :)

Comment: Question, so `newDate` would be `this.state.startDate`?

Comment: @Sylar , you should format `moment.js` date as a string to pass it as a param (like you do in the question)

Comment: Ok. I got `ArgumentError (invalid date): strptime`. Im using `@new_date = DateTime.strptime(params[:new_date], '%Y-%m-%d %H-%M')`

Comment: If you would update your answer to my post edit, I'll gladly accept this as the answer. Thanks.